# How to access git url in properties step of jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am using the Active Choices plugin, how do you access the git url in the script section of a properties section of a jenkinsfile?

For example, in the following section marked "script", how would I access env.GIT_URL???

To be clear, I can access "${env.GIT_URL}" within stages of the pipeline just fine, but this returns null within the script of the properties...

Also tried looking at `jenkinsProject` within the script but returns: "No such property: jenkinsProject for class: Script1"

Also tried `scm.getUserRemoteConfigs()[0].getUrl()`, but returns: "No such property: scm for class: Script1"

Also tried `build.getBuildVariables().get('GIT_URL')`, but returns "No such property: build for class: Script1"

Also tried `System.getenv('GIT_URL')`, but returns null

Also tried:
    `def thr = Thread.currentThread()
    def build = thr?.executable
    def envVarsMap = build.parent.builds[0].properties.get("envVars")`
but this returns "No such property: executable for class: java.lang.Thread"

Also tried: 
    `def build = this.getProperty('binding').getVariable('build')
    def listener = this.getProperty('binding').getVariable('listener')
    def env = build.getEnvironment(listener)`
, but returns "No such property: build for class: groovy.lang.Binding"

```
node{
  properties([
      parameters([
          [$class: 'ChoiceParameter',
              choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
              description: 'The names',
              filterable: false,
              name: 'Name',
              randomName: 'choice-parameter-5631314439613978',
              script: [
                  $class: 'GroovyScript',
                  script: [
                      classpath: [],
                      sandbox: false,
                      // note, changes to this script need script approval in Jenkins (see jenkins/scriptApproval)
                      script: """
                                 // how to get env.git_url at this point?
                                 return "anything"
                              """
                  ]
              ]
          ],
      ])
  ])
}
pipeline {
  ...
}
```

I'm using Jenkins v2.121.2, with Active Choices plugin v2.1

Comment: I have tried a number of suggestions on that page with no luck... I'll edit the above and document what I've tried/results I get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've managed to get to an answer... escaping it all seems to work...

\"${scm.userRemoteConfigs[0].url}\"

So my properties in my Jenkinsfile look like this... Note, this also needs to be wrapped in a node block.

```
node{
properties([
    parameters([
        [$class: 'ChoiceParameter',
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
            description: 'All tags',
            filterable: false,
            name: 'Tag',
            randomName: 'choice-parameter-5631314439613999',
            script: [
                $class: 'GroovyScript',
                script: [
                    classpath: [],
                    sandbox: false,
                    script: """
                              def sout = new StringBuilder(), serr = new StringBuilder()
                              def proc = String.format(\"git ls-remote --tags %s\", \"${scm.userRemoteConfigs[0].url}\").execute()
                              proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
                              proc.waitForOrKill(30000)

                              def tagList = sout.tokenize().findAll { it.endsWith(\"{}\") }
                              return tagList.sort()
                            """
                ]
            ]
        ],
        [$class: 'ChoiceParameter',
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
            description: 'Build Configuration - whether to build the solution/project as either a Debug or Release build.',
            filterable: false,
            name: 'Config',
            randomName: 'choice-parameter-5631314439615999',
            script: [
                $class: 'GroovyScript',
                script: [
                    classpath: [],
                    sandbox: false,
                    // note, changes to this script need script approval in Jenkins (see jenkins/scriptApproval)
                    script: """
                              return ['Debug:selected', 'Release']
                            """
                ]
            ]
        ],
    ])
])
}
```